# How do I calculate standard error given a linear model summary in R?

Tags: r, regression, self-study

Using R summary of a linear model, I'm supposed to calculate standard error and the t-value. I know the t-value is the estimate divided by the standard error, but how do I find the standard error?

This is the output I was given:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Ozone ~ Temp)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-40.922 -17.459  -0.874  10.444 118.078 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -147.6461    18.7553  -7.872 2.76e-12 ***
Temp           2.4391     ______  ______  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 23.92 on 109 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.488,     Adjusted R-squared:  0.4833 
F-statistic: 103.9 on 1 and 109 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: The output indicates a large range of values for the model residuals even though the R-square indicates about 48% of the variance is explained by the model.  The coefficients table gives you the standard error,value of the t statistics and the p-value (Pr(>|t|)) for each regression parameter to indicate significance.  The p-values are surprisingly small. I don't know why the standard error and t value are missing for the temp parameter.  It might be clear if we could see the data file for temperature.

Comment: For clarification, the standard error and t-value were purposely taken out of the output. I'm supposed to figure out how to find them given the rest of the data.

Comment: Did they give you the data or just the code and output?

Comment: Just the code and the output

Comment: I don't think there is enough information to do this but I could be wrong. The fact that the denominator degrees of freedom for the F test of 109 indicates that there are 110 observations.

Comment: Everything builds from confidence intervals!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple linear regression with one predictor, so the t-statistic is the same as the square-root of the F-statistic (given in the last line of the output).
This gives $t=\sqrt{103.9}=10.19$.

The t-statistic is also equal to the coefficient divided by the standard error,
$$t=\frac{\hat\beta}{{\rm SE}}$$so the standard error must be
$${\rm SE}=\frac{\hat\beta}{t}=\frac{2.4391}{10.19} = 0.2393.$$

Comment: Thank you!! This problem has been bothering me for hours

Comment: +1 Very good.  I should have thought of that!  As this is a self-study problem an answer with explicit hints rather than a complete solution is preferred.